# UIActionSheet pass touches through?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I'm looking to use a `UIActionSheet` kind of like a contextual message box (with no action buttons at all and just a label in the bubble with an arrow pointing at something). Since there are no actions the user can take, I would like it to not require a tap to dismiss, but I can't see any way (such as a `passthroughViews` property) to allow this.

It's probably not designed for this, but it does happen to be handy for it.

Comment: Why not use a `UIPopoverController` instead? Create a simple view with  the content. Don't use `UIActionSheet` in ways it is not intended.

Comment: @rmaddy Mostly because it's more convenient to just pass the thing a string and have it size itself automatically, however you're probably right, it does make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is some example code of how to show an UIAlertView and dismiss it automatically.

**Show it:**

```
- (void)show 
{
     UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
     alert.tag = tag;
     [alert show];
}
```

**Dismiss it:**

```
- (void)dismiss
{
    for (UIWindow* w in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows)
        for (NSObject* o in w.subviews)
            if ([o isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
                UIAlertView *alert = (UIAlertView*) o;
                if (alert.tag == tag)
                    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView*)o cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
            }
}
```

Yo can call the dismiss method after a couple of seconds:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(dismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0 inModes:nil];
```